# ansible adding key to ssh-agent before executing a command

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that runs a shell script via command module. TIs there a way to add a key to the ssh agent for executing the command? the script I am running require a very specific key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The simplest way to do this would be to specify `--private-key` during playbook execution:

`ansible-play -u username --private-key play.yml`

- Another option is to add `ansible.cfg` file in playbook directory with the following contents:

`private_key_file=/path/to/file.pem`

( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file )

Comment: [ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes
did the trick